# Odoo - outgoing email KeyError: 'body'

Tags: email, odoo, odoo-9

In Odoo 9 community outgoing email used to work (smtp configured, etc.), but now I get the following error when trying to send any email (invoice, internal note, etc.) from any account, for any template.

Things I changed since it worked that might (or might not) be linked to this issue:

- I installed and uninstalled the SMTP Server Per User plugin
- I changed the "from: " email address in the email templates

Any clue why this occurs? Or any clue what this "body" key is and where it is supposed to be defined? Thanks!

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 605, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 642, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 316, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 893, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 471, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 998, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 986, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 238, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 369, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 191, in send_mail_action
    return self.send_mail()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py", line 1306, in send_mail
    return super(MailComposeMessage, self).send_mail(auto_commit=auto_commit)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 248, in send_mail
    ActiveModel.browse(res_id).message_post(message_type='comment', subtype=subtype, **mail_values)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 1712, in message_post
    new_message = MailMessage.create(values)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py", line 864, in create
    user_signature=self.env.context.get('mail_notify_user_signature', True))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py", line 926, in _notify
    partners._notify(self, force_send=force_send, user_signature=user_signature)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/models/res_partner.py", line 127, in _notify
    ('notify_email', '!=', 'none')])._notify_by_email(message, force_send=force_send, user_signature=user_signature)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/models/res_partner.py", line 178, in _notify_by_email
    new_emails, new_recipients_nbr = self._notify_send(not_values['body'], not_values['subject'], recipient_template_values['not_followers'], **base_mail_values)
KeyError: 'body'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve the issue myself, but the person who did told me it came from a translation file and an "<" sign that was interpreted as a smaller than in the python code. So he changed the translation file to remove the smaller than.

Comment: where is location of this file? I also have this error!

Answer (score 1):

***@v11 odoo community***

**Solved Error : Odoo - outgoing email KeyError: 'body'**

When Other User  sends message on contacts page it gives outgoing email KeyError: 'body'.
This Error is occur from Mail Template : [mail module /data/ mail_data.xml]

so change Your Template Body code Or You Can Also inherit Mail Template:

1. **Remove extra content in this mail_data.xml file**.

   ```
   % if ctx.get('website_url'):       
   % endif
   ```
2. **Only This code Work Properly** :

   ```
   <p style="color: #555555;">
     Sent by
     % if ctx.get('website_url'):
       <a href="${ctx['website_url']}" style="text-decoration:none; color: #875A7B;">
     % endif
     ${ctx.get('company_name')}
     </a>
     using
     <a target="_blank" href="https://www.odoo.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #875A7B;">Odoo</a>.
   </p>
   ```

**Also Reference** : https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8yMK.png